# Word addin, Getting the whole document loaded again

Tags: javascript, ms-word, add-in, office-js

I am developing an addin for Word 2016/365 to grab Word templates and to be able via contentcontrols alter information in header and footer. To begin with there will be only two templates to work with. I'm using ooxml and getting the xmldocument via XMLHttpRequest:

```
    //Function to get ooxmldocument via XMLHttpRequest

function getTemplate(fileName) {

    var myOOXMLRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var myXML;

    myOOXMLRequest.open('GET', fileName, false);

    myOOXMLRequest.send();

    if (myOOXMLRequest.status === 200) {

        myXML = myOOXMLRequest.responseText;
        console.log('myXML VariabelData: ', myXML);
        return myXML;        
    }
    return "" ;
}
```

I insert the template via this:

```
    // Insert a 'default' template with logo and contentControllers in header and footer of the xml
function insertDefaultTemplate() {

    Word.run(function (context) {
        var body = context.document.body;

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync().then(function () {

            var t = getTemplate('/Content/Templates/BrevmallMD.xml', 'Replace');

            body.insertText("Formaterar dokument...", Word.InsertLocation.start);

            return context.sync().then(function () {  

                body.insertOoxml(t, Word.InsertLocation.replace);   


                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    showNotification("Standardmallen är införd!", "Välj användaruppgifter.");
                    });
                });
            })
        }).catch(function (error) {
            errorHandler();
    })
}
```

With some other functions I get to insert new info to contentcontrollers (that are in the document from start) via buttons and jQuery.

The problem is when you want to insert the document again. It doesnt load the original document as it is. it seem to get merged in the existing one precent in the addin.

I want to be able to load a new document as it is, not load a document and then it get merged with the existing one. I have seen a lot of example on office devcenter regardin putting in stuff in body and in sections but not to the whole document. How do I do that =) ?